Using Taylor's inequality to estimate the accuracy of approximation with 2 bounds.
enter image description hereT2(x)=1-(x-1)+(x-1)^2
the question is Use Taylor's Inequality to estimate the accuracy of the approximation
f(x) ≈ Tn(x)
when x lies in the given interval. (Round your answer to eight decimal places.)
|R2(x)| ≤
I don't understand how to solve this please help me out. Thank you.
